# Command to unlock "Locked" files on OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, file-attributes

I copied a lot of read-only files from a Windows system to my Mac.  When viewing the Info for each file using "Get Info", I can see they are Locked.  I'm writing a bash script to copy over some files and I'm getting an error that says "Operation not permitted"  So, first I need to unlock the files.  Since I'll be pulling files from the Windows system often, I want my script to unlock these files.

What is the terminal command to unlock "Locked" files on OSX?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

To unlock files you can use:

```
chflags -R nouchg /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/WITH/LOCKED/FILES/
```

- `chflags` = change flags on files/folders such as "locked"
- `-R` = recursive or for everything and follow directories within the specified directory
- `nouchg` = means the file can be changed
- `/PATH/` = of course is the path to the files you want to change.
  Something like:  `~/Sites/mysite/directory/with/locked/files/` works as
  well.

Comment: Looks like I found the solution just as you were responding.  I also learned that the -R is for recursive.  So, to unlock all files in the current directory use<br/>
chflags nochg *<br/>
and to change just one file<br/>
chflags nouchg onefile.txt
See: http://www.mehtanirav.com/2009/04/16/recursively-unlock-files-on-mac-os-x

Comment: There's another relevant flag `schg` which is the system immutable flag (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html)
The command to clear it is similar:
`sudo chflags noschg PATH/TO/LOCKED/FILE`

Comment: Use ```/bin/ls -lO /path/to/file``` to view the macOS ```flags``` on files. 
Notice the full path to the macOS '```ls```' command. This is needed if you have GNU Coreutils installed.

Comment: @AndyMadge - I needed to use that flag, from following directions on this page: https://www.askdavetaylor.com/how-to-delete-locked-file-on-mac-macos/. But the link you provided is dead. Do you have an updated link?

Comment: @Adam_G seems like Apple have moved the web page, but you can view the man page directly in MacOS terminal with the `man chflags` command

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 25):

This is helpful if you want to search an entire directory and unlock all files.

In the terminal `cd` to the directory

This command finds and will *print a list of them*.

```
$ find . -flags uchg
```

This command *unlocks them*.

```
$ find . -flags uchg -exec chflags nouchg {} \;
```

You can use the first command to double check that all the files are unlocked after running the second command, voilà !

Comment: While this works, it can be extremely slow for large numbers of files because it starts a new process for each file.

Comment: I find I have to use `+` : `find . -flags +uchg` even to find files that only seem to have the one flag, uchg, set.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use `SetFile -a l`, even though it does the same thing as `chflags nouchg`:

```
SetFile -a l file.ext
```

`-a l` unsets the bit for the locked attribute. You can install SetFile by downloading the Command Line Tools package from Xcode's preferences or from [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads).

Comment: This is the method that worked for me on macOS Sierra with a few files copied from a Windows machine.  
I used : SetFile -a l ~/Documents/Arduino/Samples/*

Comment: As fyi, `/usr/bin/SetFile` (`setfile`) was deprecated with Xcode 6 along as were other tools supporting Carbon development; although `SetFile` still appears to install as part of Xcode 12 additional command line tools. See `man SetFile`

Answer (score 12):

There are actually two lock flags that can be set on a file: `uchg` and `schg`. A file that has the `uchg` flag set is immutable by normal users but it is mutable by the system. A file that has the `schg` flag set is immutable by anyone. Both flags can be set at the same time.

To see which flags are set on a file, use

```
ls -lO FILE
```

That is a capital letter o, not zero.

To definitely unlock a file, you would have to execute

```
chflags nouchg,noschg FILE
```

as if both flags were set and you remove only one of them, it will still be locked.