# Why can't I hard link a certain file (Mac)?

Tags: mac, hardlink

I'm copy/linking files and have found that a certain file really does not like to be hard linked.

Both `gcp -alp Get_started_with_GoPro.url test` (gnu-cp) and `ln Get_started_with_GoPro.url test` fail with `Operation not permitted`.

Other files link fine, and `cp Get_started_with_GoPro.url test1; ln test1 test2` works just fine as well.

How can I find out what is preventing `Get_started_with_GoPro.url` file from being hard linked?

(I've also verified that other files with same permissions can hard link)

Comment: are both of your files on the same filesystem ?

Comment: Absolutely ... those commands are verbatim simplified attempts. (1 directory is not usually across multiple file systems.) `readlink Get_started_with_GoPro.url` returns nothing (indicating it's a normal file)

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is that `ls -l` does not tell all. Viewing in Finder shows a padlock and "Get Info" shows that "Locked" is ticked.

[Command to unlock "Locked" files on OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/40749/command-to-unlock-locked-files-on-os-x) has more details on how to change this from the command line.

Comment: so it's something really MacOSX related, good to know.

Comment: Well, there's `chattr +i` on linux (for immutable) http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/11/make-your-files-immutable-which-even.html